# How to override bootstrap container class for two different pages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid, less

I have two pages: landing and home. I want to set different container-width, @gutter-width and @column-width for both pages. How to achieve this?

I am using less framework and concatenating all less files, while building the code to be deployed to production. Right now the styles of one page are affecting other.

Comment: How about assigning a different `class` to the `body` tag of each page and then styling based on it?

Comment: Thanks for reply Harry. I am currently doing the same. But changing gutter-width at that level is not working. Would you mine sharing some sample example if it works for you?

Comment: No mate, I don't have any live samples. It should ideally work. Can you maybe host the pages somewhere for us to have a look? That might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the gutter width like this (example of a 3% gutter)

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/jeqase/1/

```
.alt-grid .row {margin-left:-1.5%;margin-right:-1.5%;}
.alt-grid [class*="col-"] {padding-left:1.5%;padding-right:1.5%}
```

**HTML**

```
<body class="alt-grid">
```

Then all the `[class*="col-"]` and all the `.row` will be affected.

The example above is putting alt-grid class on the body or a container around the `.row > .col-*-*` but you can also put it on the `.row` itself...

```
<div class="row alt-grid">...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alt-grid.row {margin-left:-1.5%;margin-right:-1.5%;}
.alt-grid [class*="col-"] {padding-left:1.5%;padding-right:1.5%}
```

The .container width can also be adjusted:

```
<div class="container">...</div>

.alt-grid .container { /* assumes that the .alt-grid is on the body or html tag*/
     width:100%;
     max-width:1600px;
}
```

*If you add padding on the left and right of your adjusted `.container` it must equal the negative value of the `.row` margin. For this example it must be at least 1.5% padding on the left and right. 15px padding is the default and in this example it won't interfere. If you don't have the same or more padding as the negative margin on the row, horizontal bars will show up -- naturally.*